# Converting multiple timezone to local time

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I'm saving date time in CST timezone,how to change the CST date time to local time.

Ex:

In DB,
Date time is 2013-01-21 06:50:00 and its timezone is CST.This Date Time should be converted into local current time.

Comment: Do you care about daylight saving time?

Comment: CST is not a timezone, it's an abbreviation, and it's ambiguous.  Is it China Standard Time? Cuba Standard Time? Central Standard Time (US), Central Standard Time (Australia), etc.  I hope you are storing more than just "CST" in your database. See [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/) for a full list of abbreviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save them as UTC time and then convert them to local time when loading to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

A sample code would be like

```
using System;

public class Example
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2010, 3, 14, 2, 30, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid time: {0}", 
                    TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsInvalidTime(date1));
  DateTime utcDate1 = date1.ToUniversalTime();
  DateTime date2 = utcDate1.ToLocalTime();
  Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", date1, date2);      
  }
 }
// The example displays the following output: 
//       Invalid time: True 
//   3/14/2010 2:30:00 AM --> 3/14/2010 3:30:00 AM
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Where in this example do you take into account that the OP specified that dates are stored in CST?